# SQL Function: Get next value in row

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for an SQL way to get the value from the next row.

```
   The data I have looks like:

CURR_STRT_DT    CUUR_END_DT      product 
  6/30/2019      9/28/2019         A
  6/30/2019      9/28/2019         A
  9/29/2019      12/28/2019        B
  12/29/2019     3/28/2020         C
  3/31/2019      6/29/2019         D
```

I need output as

```
 CURR_STRT_DT   CUUR_END_DT product   NEXT_SRT_DT   NEXT_END_DT
  6/30/2019      9/28/2019     A      9/29/2019      12/28/2019
  6/30/2019      9/28/2019     A      9/29/2019      12/28/2019
  9/29/2019      12/28/2019    B      12/29/2019     3/28/2020
  12/29/201      3/28/2020     C      3/31/2019      6/29/2019
  3/31/2019      6/29/2019     D      null            null
```

I tried to use lead function , last value and rank() all function but no use of it . can any one please help me to achieve above task

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/ MySQL `Lag` and `Lead` can help you to achieve the same. Can you please confirm your MySQL version.

Comment: By definition tables are UNORDERED  set so What is the order? because 3/31/2019 should be first not last.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Looks like they are ordered by `product, CURR_STRT_DT`? What I want to know is why are there duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Lead because you have a tie. So the next one is actually the same date

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a22ccbad75f728404df8de3f1354b6f)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *,  dense_rank() over (ORDER BY CURR_STRT_DT) as rn
    FROM Table1
)    
SELECT c1.*, 
      (SELECT `CURR_STRT_DT` FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 ) as `CURR_STRT_DT`,
      (SELECT `CUUR_END_DT` FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.rn = c1.rn + 1 ) as `CUUR_END_DT`
FROM cte c1;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Please check the demo and output. As I said this query put the `2019-03-31` as first

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly, MySQL `LAG` and `LEAD` function can help you to achieve the same.

Please check below query.

```
select CURR_STRT_DT,CUUR_END_DT,product,
 Lead(CURR_STRT_DT) OVER (ORDER BY CURR_STRT_DT) NEXT_SRT_DT,
 Lead(CUUR_END_DT) OVER (ORDER BY CUUR_END_DT) NEXT_END_DT
from tab_name;
```

You can also partition the data by product. I have posted the tutorial link, you can check.

**Tutorial:** http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lag-function/

Comment: I tried this approach, but for product A dates are showing up wrong. may be lead function will work only 1 row above

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `range` option for window definition to do this.  It is very handy for variable ranges:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       MIN(CURR_STRT_DT) OVER (ORDER BY CURR_STRT_DT
                               RANGE BETWEEN interval 1 day FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                              ) as CURR_END_DT
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER BY CURR_STRT_DT;
```

This should be the simplest and most efficient method.